# How to trigger a dynamically created button from another dynamically created button

Tags: jquery

In Jquery, how to trigger a dynamically created button from another dynamically created button

//Btn 1

```
$(document).on('click','#btn_1', function(){   
   //how to trigger #btn_2 from here   
});
```

//Btn 2

```
$(document).on('click','#btn_2',function(){  
    alert("Btn 2");
});
```

Please help me

Comment: `$('#btn_2').trigger('click');` same as normal

Comment: Thank you for reply. I've already tried this code, not working. Actually both the buttons are appended in DOM dynamically. Please help if any other update is there

Comment: If that is not working, then that would suggest that when you try to do the trigger, that either the element is not yet in the DOM, or that binding does not exist yet.  In either of those cases, you cannot make that logic happen until both of those cases are true.

Comment: @BappaDey what taplar suggested should work just fine. try take a look here https://jsfiddle.net/157zwo8f/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(document).on('click','#btn_1',function(){
$('#btn_2').trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: Not working, as both the buttons are appended in DOM dynamically

Comment: when #btn_1 is triggered, by then DOM has #btn_2 defined?

Comment: Thats great! I hope that the second btn was defined when first btn is triggered